# Cannot use preview camera in webView

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, camera, cordova-plugins

My app use webView. However, it can't preview camera because webView overlay on camera on android app. It's show white/blank screen but I can take a photo.

[image]

1. I tried set background transparent webView. But it isn't work.
2. I tried set "bring to front" with camera.  But it isn't work.
3. I tried set padding and margin to 0. But it isn't work.
4. I tried set View.INVISIBLE with webView it's camera can show preview but I want to show a button take a photo from webView. (it's not show "take a photo" button).
5. I tried resize (Use setLayoutParams) webview for show camera. I can take a photo but size webView deform. I want't to give webView deform. I think it we can crop webView?

[image]

PS. webView is CordovaWebView, Camera use FrameLayout.

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {


    //create or update the layout params for the container view
    FrameLayout containerView = (FrameLayout)cordova.getActivity().findViewById(containerViewId);
    if(containerView == null){
      containerView = new FrameLayout(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
      containerView.setId(containerViewId);

      FrameLayout.LayoutParams containerLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      cordova.getActivity().addContentView(containerView, containerLayoutParams);
    }
    //display camera bellow the webview
    if(toBack){
      webView.getView().setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
      ((ViewGroup)webView.getView()).bringToFront();
    }else{
      //set camera back to front
      containerView.setAlpha(opacity);
      containerView.bringToFront();
    }

    //add the fragment to the container
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = cordova.getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(containerView.getId(), fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    cb.success("Camera started");
  }
});
```